# BeanPropertyRowMapper unable to obtain fields with underscore

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I have a table that contains the following columns : `ca_2008` , `ca_2009` ,etc
when I use `BeanPropertyRowMapper` to obtain these values they only return 0 whilst it's not 0
and when I've manipulated the setters and changed it to `setca_2008` instead of `setca2008` it worked
but the problem is that according to the documentation it says that

> The names are matched either directly or by transforming a name separating the parts with underscores to the same name using "camel" case.
> [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/BeanPropertyRowMapper.html)

```
BeanPropertyRowMapper<ClassName> rowMapper = new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(ClassName.class);
rowMapper.setPrimitivesDefaultedForNullValue(true);
List<ClassName> c = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, rowMapper);
```

how can I obtain these values without changing the setters ?!
should I necessarily switch to `RowMapper` instead of `BeanPropertyRowMapper` ?!

thanks in adavnce

Comment: You cannot. I suspect that is due to the fact that there are numbers and not regular camel-case names. You might want to add an improvement request for the `BeanPropertyRowMapper`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple workaround for it, use column aliasing in your sql query which you are passing to jdbcTemplate BeanPropertyRowMapper.
For example, If an employee table has column emp_id and your employee bean attribute is empId having setter as setEmpId(long empId);
Simply write query as

> select emp_id as empId from employee;

Now the BeanPropertyRowMapper will simply map the selected column to the empId attribute.